# Declaring a superclass variable then instantiating it with a subclass in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, declaration, instantiation

I am a little confused and looking for some clarification on the differences and different benefits for two different approaches for the declaration and instantiation of a Map.

What is the difference between

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>;
```

AND

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>;
```

What is the benefit or reason for declaring a superclass variable then instantiating it with a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "programming to the interface".  (`Map` is an interface, not a class.)  This allows code that only needs `Map` operations not to care which kind of `Map` it really is.

You could easily switch out the `HashMap` for, say, a `TreeMap` if you feel it's appropriate, and no other code would change.

Other similar questions:

- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)
- [What does it mean to program to a interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413543/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-a-interface)

Other references:

- [Code to the Interface, Even if the Interface is a Class](http://java.dzone.com/articles/code-interface-even-if)
- [Design Principles from Design Patterns](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) talks about this also.

Answer (score 1):

The first version uses a Hashmap for its implementation, but only exposes the members of Map in myMap.

In other words, you get the functionality of HashMap, but only through the interface of Map.  It's done this way so that you can change out the implementation, but still use the same interface members.