# The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing this weird problem with my Eclipse.
Getting this error

`The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>`

I cleaned and build my project again.
Checked my Configure Build path and ensured that *JRESystemLibrary* is above *MavenDependencies* in *Order and Export.*

Googled as well but I can't find any issue with my code.
Why is the error popping up.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you call `Set` it is being taken as **your class** Set, not `java.util.Set`.

Change the declaration to `java.util.Set` and it should be resolved.

Comment: He could also just do `HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();` instead on that line.

Comment: @DennisMeng No, That's a bad idea.

Comment: Am I missing something silly? (i.e. is there something I should know, in case I'm having a brainfart right now?)

Comment: @DennisMeng Yup. [Programming with interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413543/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-a-interface)

Answer (score 7):

Your main method thinks Set is the class that it's contained in.

You want java.util.Set

My suggestion would be to rename your class :p

Answer (score 3):

I have also gone through the same error but it was resolved just by changing in some properties of project.

Right Click on your project --> Properties --> Select "Java Build Path" from Right hand side panel --> Select "Order and Export" tab --> Click on you JRE System Library or JDK Library --> Click on "Up" button and move it to first position --> Click Ok and clean & build your project.

Do repeat this for all other dependents project as well, if have any dependency.

It resolved my issue because previously the java files were picking other library and packages not from jre package as it was ordered set in last priority.

Thanks,
Shwetank R.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and followed below steps

Right Click on your project --> Properties --> Select "Java Build Path" from Right hand side panel --> Select "Order and Export" tab -->  and checked JRE system Library is present on top or not id it is present on TOP select this and click Apply. Then create new class

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.Set;

public class ChildWindow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Existing Url");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Url-1");
    driver.findElement
    (By.xpath(".//*[@id='footer-list']/li[4] /a")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    //get all windows ids -driver.getWindowHandles()
    Set<String>ids=driver.getWindowHandles();
     Iterator<String> it =ids.iterator();
     String Childid1=it.next();
     String Childid2=it.next();
     driver.switchTo().window(Childid2);
     System.out.println("2nd Url");
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


   }

  }
```