# The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <K>

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compilation, rad

I am getting the following error:

[image]

This is happening in My RAD and Eclipse when i try to run using WAS 8.0 JRE runtime.

Can somebody suggest?

Comment: What is the actual type of the object that you are passing to `signatureMap`?

Comment: One thing to check: go to the project properties and find the "Build Path". Is it using the correct (1.8) version of the JRE system library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374315/the-type-set-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-integer)

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, your own class called `Set` (or some other class called `Set`) which is picked up instead of `java.util.Set`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your RAD Build path and compiler level.

Also check you import statement. Map should be java.util.Map;

Your iteration procedure is correct and code is fine. you can iterate a map in another way  as shown below :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```