# Parent in declaration and new child

Tags: java, collections, declaration

I know these 3 different kinds of declarations:

```
1) ClassParent var = new ClassParent ();
2) ClassChild var = new ClassChild();
3) ClassParent var = new ClassChild();
   Map<Character, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Third case really common with collections. 
Could you let me know the difference between all of them, advantages, disadvantages and how you know when to use one of them over the others. Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at the [help] to find out what are appropriate questions on StackOverflow. Asking for a broad tutorial, and not asking a specific question, is not appropriate and will likely be closed quickly as "too broad".

Comment: I feel this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1413543