# Creating a multidimensional array from array lists

Tags: java

I need to convert a set of ArrayLists of n length to a JTable.

```java
ArrayList<Double> operand1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> operand2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> userAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> correctAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each of these Arraylists will be the same length.

I'm having some trouble converting them into a multidimensional array where I can eventually use that array in a JTable.

I have tried a number of things.

```java
// converting the single list to an array: error obj to double
Double [] arr = new Double[operand1.size()];
arr = operand.toArray();

// Shot in the dark
arr = Arrays.copyOf(operand1.toString(), operand1.size(), Double.class);
```

The goal would be to....

```java
// Needs a name for each column
Double [][] data = {operand1, operand2, userAnswer, correctAnswer}
//or individually add them via
JTable table = new Table();
table.add(operand)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if there is a way to make this into a method that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

First, please program to the `List<Double>` interface instead of the `ArrayList` concrete type. Second, you can use `Arrays.asList(double...)` to create a `List` in one line. Finally, you can use [`List.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) to convert your `List<Double>` into a `Double[]`. Like,

```
List<Double> operand1 = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0);
List<Double> operand2 = Arrays.asList(3.0, 4.0);
List<Double> userAnswer = Arrays.asList(5.0, 6.0);
List<Double> correctAnswer = Arrays.asList(7.0, 8.0);
Double[][] data = { operand1.toArray(new Double[0]), operand2.toArray(new Double[0]),
        userAnswer.toArray(new Double[0]), correctAnswer.toArray(new Double[0]) };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
```

Which outputs

```
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0]]
```

Comment: I new to java and have a lot to learn. In the case of a List<> vs ArrayList<> what is the difference between ArrayList being concrete and List  ?

Comment: [What does it mean to program to a interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1413543/2970947)

Comment: Yeah. From the program side, is there a discernible difference when it comes to handeling a List vs ArrayList

Comment: Every `AbstractList`, `AbstractSequentialList`, `ArrayList`, `AttributeList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `RoleList`, `RoleUnresolvedList`, `Stack` and `Vector` is a `List`. The reverse is not true. So if you program to the `List` interface, you can use any of those (plus any other custom) concrete types. If you program to `ArrayList`, you can only use an `ArrayList`.