# Why exactly does a `Comparator` using a primitive `int` work in this code? If auto-boxing, at what point does that happen?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, autoboxing

I wrote this code as a [solution on another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71606829/642706):

```java
record Person( String name , int age ) { }
List < Person > persons =
        List.of(
                new Person( "Alice" , 52 ) ,
                new Person( "Bob" , 23 ) ,
                new Person( "Carol" , 39 )
        );

List < Person > sorted =
        persons
                .stream()
                .sorted( Comparator.comparing( Person :: age ) )
                .toList();
```

This code runs successfully on [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17).

> persons.toString() = [Person[name=Alice, age=52], Person[name=Bob, age=23], Person[name=Carol, age=39]]
>
> sorted.toString() = [Person[name=Bob, age=23], Person[name=Carol, age=39], Person[name=Alice, age=52]]

Upon further thought, I am surprised this code works. I pass a method reference for the accessor method (“getter”) on the [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) call.

```
Comparator.comparing( Person :: age )
```

… but `age` member field, and the return type of this method, are both `int` primitive, not an object.

This leaves me puzzled as to why this works, because I would think the comparator requires objects, not primitives.

Is there some [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing) at play here? If so, exactly where? What triggers the compiler or runtime to perform auto-boxing in this code?

I am hoping for a narrow and precise answer rather than same hand-waving. The hand-waving was already done when I authored the code! So, now, I am *not* asking out of practicality, as clearly the code is intuitive and the code works. The `language-lawyer` tag is indeed appropriate here, as I am asking about the “intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages”.

Comment: You are right, you should (probably) use `Comparator.comparingInt()` to avoid the needless boxing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave as an exercise for the reader that the resolution process for `Person::age` identifies the *potentially-applicable method* `int age()` as an *exact method reference expression*. Having identified the target method, from [JLS 15.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2):

> A method reference expression is *congruent* with a function type if both of the following are true:
>
> - The function type identifies a single compile-time declaration corresponding to the reference.
> - One of the following is true: […]
>
>   - The result of the function type is R, and the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to the return type of the invocation type (§15.12.2.6) of the chosen compile-time declaration is R' (where R is the target type that may be used to infer R'), and neither R nor R' is void, and R' is compatible with R in an assignment context.

The function type here is `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`. `T` is clearly `Person`, and the signature of `comparing` requires some `U extends Comparable<? super U>`.

The type `int` is *compatible with `Integer` in an assignment context* and then subsequently also compatible with `Comparable<Integer>` ([JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)):

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following: […]
>
> - a boxing conversion followed by a widening reference conversion