# Difference between blocking deque vs linked blocking deque

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

What is the difference between the two in Java? Is it just that blocking deque uses an array and linked blocking deque uses a linked list? I want to know this so that I can make a decision about which data structure I want to use for my audio track queue.

Comment: Seriously ... didn't you look at the javadocs?  And interface is not a data structure.  It is an API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) is an **interface**, and [`java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) is a concrete **class** implementing that interface. In fact, it is the only (public) implementation of `BlockingDeque` in the JavaSE API, so there is no choice to make (unless you want to implement your own or find another library implementing another `BlockingDeque`).

See also [What does it mean to program to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413543/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)